# How to create and infinite while loop- php

Tags: php, sql

basically I have a simple user page which I access after logging in via a login page. In the user page, there is my personal data displayed from my previous registration. And there is also a form where I can enter new information such as my favourite color and hobby (which I can insert multiple times). All the records goes into the DB succesfully. The problem is, everytime I submit a new data from the form in the user page, my personal data that are displayed in the same page dissapears. When I check the DB, nothing is lost, everything remains there. The only problem is, everytime I submit a data, my personal data which is displayed on the same page dissapears. BUt when I log in, it is there again. I suspect it might be due to non-infinite while looping everytime I press the submit button to insert new information.

How do I create an infinite while loop if this is the problem.??please help. If this is not the problem, please help me. tq so much. Below is partial of my script. tq.

```
    <?php

//useracc-test.php

//start session
session_start();


// require 'lib/password.php';
require 'connect-test.php';


//retrieving part below

$userName= isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
//$id= isset($_POST['id']);

$query = "SELECT id, name, username, telno FROM users WHERE username = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $userName);
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result(); 

?>

<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#apDiv2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 272px;
    top: 148px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 338px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#apDiv3 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 37px;
    top: 379px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 157px;
    z-index: 2;
}
</style>
<link href="SpryAssets/SpryTabbedPanels.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryTabbedPanels.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="apDiv3">
<div id="TabbedPanels1" class="TabbedPanels">
  <ul class="TabbedPanelsTabGroup">
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">Tab 1</li>
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">Tab 2</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="TabbedPanelsContentGroup">
    <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">
      <p>


      </p>
      <?php while($row = $res->fetch_array()): ?>
      <p><?php echo $row['id']; ?></p>
      <p><?php echo $row['name']; ?></p>
      <p><?php echo $row['username']; ?></p>
      <p><?php echo $row['telno']; ?>
      <?php endwhile; ?>








        <?php



 if(isset($_POST['submit']))

   {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $name2 = $_POST['name2'];
    $color2 = $_POST['color2'];
    $hobby2 = $_POST['hobby2'];



    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO useradvert (id,name2,color2,hobby2) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("isss",$id,$name2,$color2,$hobby2);
    $stmt->execute();

   // $stmt->close();
   // $conn->close();
   } 


    ?>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">
      <form name="form2" method="post" action="useracc-test.php">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>id :
          <input type="text" name="id" id="id">
        </p>
        <p>name :
          <input type="text" name="name2" id="name2">
        </p>
        <p>color2 :
          <input type="text" name="color2" id="color2">
        </p>
        <p>hobby2 :
          <input type="text" name="hobby2" id="hobby2">
        </p>
        <p>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
        </p>
      </form>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>    
  <script type="text/javascript">
var TabbedPanels1 = new Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels("TabbedPanels1");
  </script>
</body>
               </html>
```

Comment: The script that you submit the form to needs to redisplay the data. Or you can submit it using AJAX, so the page doesn't reload.

Comment: What do you want to output?
It should be like
while($row = $res->fetch_array($SQL_QUERY) {
echo $row['some_val_in_db'];
}

Comment: OMG. what is AJAX. im only familiar  with php.

Comment: "How do I create an infinite while loop" <-- never do this.

Comment: yes, correct what you are saying. I want it to redisplay.

Comment: You can try to tell us what you're trying to accomplish. I don't think your question is accurate.

Comment: I tried this ($row = $res->fetch_array($SQL_QUERY)..putting a variable in the bracket..but I get error

Comment: Post more php, preferably the entire function where you receive post data and where you read it, also, what error??

Comment: @linda can you post whole code?

Comment: I posted a partial script above..

Comment: Ok..whole code?? ok wait a moment.

Comment: Tqs Barmar, should I put header on top of page or below?

Comment: It seems im having problem logging in when i use header you gave me

Comment: it says  "This webpage has a redirect loop

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS " any ideas?. please help

Comment: The problem is not solved. How come someone tick on the arrow answers to be up?

Comment: Hi Thomas.. tqs for the reply. but im not getting there. I tried what you suggest. basically, I just want the data which are currently displayed in the user page to be "re-displayed" everytime I press the submit button. But in my case, when I press the submit button, the data dissapears. Any suggestions? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

When you submit a form, the browser refreshes the page with whatever the submission form returns. So after the script updates the database, it needs to display the new contents of your profile, just like the original profile page does.

A simple way to do this is for the script to send a redirect back to the page that displays the profile form. When it's done, it can do:

```
header("Location: profile.php");
```

Another option is to use AJAX to submit the changes, rather than normal HTTP form submission. You'll need to learn Javascript for this.

Answer (score 0):

the code would be:

```
while (true) {
 //loop body
}
```

BUT in PHP code stops executing after the `max_execution_time` expires (`ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);`). You don't want an infinite loop in PHP because you want output from PHP and that will only happen after the script finishes.

Infinite loops are good for embedded code where the machine has to keep running code like a robot or a clockradio.

Answer (score 0):

tq to all for the sugesstions. I appreciate. I apologise if my language is not polite because english is my 3rd language at home. It is not my native language. This is how i speak. I already solved the problem. I just use "print" function and made minor modifications. and the data never disappear. problem solved.tq all.